# Add pop up Date in google sheet to set date and time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I using Data Validation to set up date in cell but I need to select time hour and minute.
[image: Data Validation]

This is the date set pop up.

[image: date set pop up]

I try to set time but don't see time selection in pop up.
I want to add hour and minute in this pop up.
If not able to do that any code  in app script to do this work

Answer (score 0):

The date picker only allows to pick dates without times. You can build a time picker using a list of times. It might be overkill though. See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/74366/is-there-an-option-to-add-a-time-picker-on-google-sheets)